# How can I save a unique string by incrementing it in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, auto-increment

How can I save a unique string to my database and if the value exists increment it.

The behaviour I'm after is similar to when you save a file e.g. foo.txt, foo1.txt

I do NOT want to return a 'not unique value' error message.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end

Person.create(:name => 'Dave') # => 'Dave'
Person.create(:name => 'Dave') # => 'Dave1'
Person.create(:name => 'Dave') # => 'Dave2'
```

I'm using ruby, rails and mysql

Comment: One approach I could take would be to search for all occurrences with a regex and do a count.

I could use this value on a activerecord hook to change the name `before_validation` 

    Person.where(:name => /^Dave/).count

Comment: I like DDAZZA's approach. I would only add a parameter `:on`, ie: `before_validation(on: :create) do ... end`. That will limit this logic to betriggered only when `create`ing the record.

Comment: We just did this and in the end went with appending the object id to the name since it seemed easier.

Comment: You're going to have to be very careful about race conditions here, so be sure to have a fallback method that retries if if the first save didn't succeed. Theoretically you'd want to try a number of times in case of a wild coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any rails or mysql features to do this so I created the follow 3 methods and

```
  def unique_name(name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    if Person.exists?(:name => name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      generate_unique_name(name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

  def similar_names(name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Person.where("name LIKE ?", "#{name}%").pluck(:name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

  def generate_unique_name(name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    number = similar_names(name).map{ |a| a.scan(/\d+$/).max.to_i }.compact.max.to_i + 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    "#{name} #{number}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end   

  ...

  Person.create(:name => unique_name('Dave'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set validation uniqueness to your model . You can use something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 before_create :check_and_increment


 private
 def check_and_increment
   if Person.exists? name: self.name
     similar_persons = get_all_with_same_name self.name
     next_num = similar_persons.max_by{|m| m.scan(/\d+/)}.scan(/\d+/).first.nil? ? 1 : similar_persons.max_by{|m| m.scan(/\d+/)}.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i + 1
     self.name = "#{self.name}#{next_num}"
   else
     true
   end 
 end

 def get_all_with_same_name name
   where("name LIKE ?", 'name%')     
 end

end
```

This is simple idea for your problem. Need to be carefull with persons like Anna and Annastasia, for example .  These persons has different names but their names are overlap.

Hope this will help you .

Comment: I think this answer would work but I think there should be validation.

Comment: Not sure why, if you set some kind of validation in callback ?